# SWIG Python wrapper: import numpy conditionally

Tags: python, c, numpy, swig

My goal is to configure `SWIG` with Python

- to import `numpy` if a specific `numpy` version is available and
- not to import `numpy` when a specific `numpy` version is missing. When the API function that supports `numpy` is called by the user, an error message should be issued.

I have tried to integrate `numpy` with `SWIG` in the following way:

```
%include "numpy.i"

%init %{
import_array();
%}

%apply (double* IN_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(const double* mymatrix, int n)};
```

But when I import my `SWIG` generated Python module I get the following error:

```
numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

As far as I know this issue can be solved by updating the `numpy` package to the latest version (currently I have 1.12.1 installed).

But I cannot expect everyone using my API to do the same (install/update `numpy`), especially when someone does not want to use that one API function.

Comment: [“In order to make use of the C-API from another extension module, the import_array function must be called.”](https://numpy.org/doc/1.16/reference/c-api.array.html#importing-the-api) Doesn't sound like it's possible.

Comment: Should be possible to do that using dlsym, but I'll need to hack around some code to prove it

Comment: I've done some testing here - Can you clarify a little more though: are you looking to handle the case where at build time things may not match, or at run time they don't? (Or both?) I.e. do you want to produce a binary that runs regardless of whether or not numpy exists, or do you want to make source code buildable? The answer is slightly different for both

Comment: @Flexo, thank you for the question, I'd like to produce a binary that runs regardless of whether or not numpy exists on the user's computer. The API has e.g. 100 functions and only two of these functions will have a numpy array input parameter according to my plans. If a user does not use these functions, numpy should not be loaded/needed to be on the user's computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is definitely possible to do. Assuming the goal is to build a shared object/DLL once and run it on multiple systems, some of which will have an appropriate numpy version installed. Our goal is to cause the numpy specific functionality to error gracefully when at runtime there is no numpy support available.

To achieve this we've got two issues to solve:

1. We must make sure that our module can still be imported successfully
2. We must make sure that numpy specific functionality is either missing entirely or fails gracefully if the import of numpy functionality failed.

We can do this in a number of different ways. Firstly though I defined some functionality for testing, with run.py as:

```
import test

test.printit() # Must always work

print(repr(test.range(100))) # Must either fail gracefully or succeed if numpy usable
```

These functions are implemented in my testing as:

```
%inline %{
static void printit(void) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Hello world\n");
}

static void range(int *rangevec, int n)
{
        int i;

        for (i=0; i< n; i++)
                rangevec[i] = i;
}
%}
```

where range comes straight from [some numpy documentation](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/SWIG_NumPy_examples.html)

## Single module, typemap checking

The first idea that springs to mind here is to wrap our call to `import_array` in our module init with some C API code that tests for an exception and clears it but sets a flag if this occurs.

We can solve problem #1 as suggested using the exception handling of [Python's C API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html):

```
%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
static int have_numpy;
%}

%include "numpy.i"

%init %{
// Try and run import_array() - at build time we need it to be defined
_import_array();
// But at runtime we check if it worked or not:
if (PyErr_Occurred()) {
        // Exception occurred during import of numpy
        have_numpy = 0;
        PyErr_Clear();
}
else {
        have_numpy = 1;
}
fprintf(stderr, "Runtime numpy check: %d\n", have_numpy);
%}
```

Note that we had to call `_import_array` instead of `import_array` here as `import_array` was also catching the exception and printing lots of unhelpfully verbose stuff when the import failed in some of my testing.

This is all well and good, but without a solution to issue 2 we won't be failing gracefully when numpy imports fail:

```
Runtime numpy check: 0
Hello world
Segmentation fault
```

Opps! So we need a way to hook into the calling of `range`, but not `printit` and then raise an exception nicely. For this first case I looked at a few things. Initially I tried to use `%exception`, since that has nice function matching syntax, however the hook you get for this is too late into the call, we've already used the numpy typemaps and explode before we can prevent it using that.

Instead I used `-debug-tmsearch` argument to SWIG to pick a typemap that met two properties: firstly numpy itself doesn't already use it (this keeps things simpler) and secondly it occurs early on during the call. The `default` typemap makes a good candidate for this, so we can use that (with a macro to avoid repetition) nicely in a complete SWIG interface that meets our initial goals:

```
%module test

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
static int have_numpy;
%}

%include "numpy.i"

%init %{
// Try and run import_array() - at build time we need it to be defined
_import_array();
// But at runtime we check if it worked or not:
if (PyErr_Occurred()) {
        // Exception occurred during import of numpy
        have_numpy = 0;
        PyErr_Clear();
}
else {
        have_numpy = 1;
}
fprintf(stderr, "Runtime numpy check: %d\n", have_numpy);
%}

// Handle this gracefully
%define %requires_numpy(fn)
%typemap(default) fn {
        if (!have_numpy) {
                PyErr_SetString(PyExc_NotImplementedError, "Unimplemented without numpy runtime");
                SWIG_fail;
        }
}
%enddef

// For testing below:

// This must be before the %apply or typemap use
%requires_numpy((int *ARGOUT_ARRAY1, int DIM1));

%apply (int* ARGOUT_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(int* rangevec, int n)}

%inline %{
static void printit(void) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Hello world\n");
}

static void range(int *rangevec, int n)
{
        int i;

        for (i=0; i< n; i++)
                rangevec[i] = i;
}
%}
```

Without numpy we get this from run.py now:

```
Runtime numpy check: 0
Hello world
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(repr(test.range(100)))
NotImplementedError: Unimplemented without numpy runtime
```

With numpy we get:

```
Hello world
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
       34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
       51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67,
       68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84,
       85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99],
      dtype=int32)
```

## Single module, additional Python code

We can implement our exception throwing in Python also, using [`%pythonprepend`](https://swig.org/Doc4.0/Python.html#Python_nn42) if we prefer. This is the same as before, except we use Python to raise the exception and have exposed `have_numpy` to the Python module for it to work with:

```
%module test

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
static int have_numpy;
%}

const int have_numpy;

%include "numpy.i"

%init %{
// Try and run import_array() - at build time we need it to be defined
_import_array();
// But at runtime we check if it worked or not:
if (PyErr_Occurred()) {
        // Exception occurred during import of numpy
        have_numpy = 0;
        PyErr_Clear();
}
else {
        have_numpy = 1;
}
fprintf(stderr, "Runtime numpy check: %d\n", have_numpy);
%}

// Handle this gracefully
%define %requires_numpy(fn)
%pythonprepend fn %{
if not have_numpy: raise NotImplementedError("This requires numpy")
%}
%enddef

// For testing below:

%requires_numpy(range);

%apply (int* ARGOUT_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(int* rangevec, int n)}

%inline %{
static void printit(void) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Hello world\n");
}

static void range(int *rangevec, int n)
{
        int i;

        for (i=0; i< n; i++)
                rangevec[i] = i;
}
%}
```

I slightly prefer this given it means we can now name the functions that need numpy instead of interfering with their typemaps.

## Split into two modules, cross import

Finally another alternative would be to split our module into two separate modules. By putting the numpy specific functions into another module and attempting to import that we can achieve the same behaviour still. We can use `%import` to still share some types and code between the two modules. I've not completed an example of this as it's (possibly?) more complicated than you were looking for, but an outline would be something like:

```
%module test

%inline %{
static void printit(void) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Hello world\n");
}
%}

%pythoncode %{
try:
  from test_numpy import *
except:
  pass # This is fine
%}
```

and

```
%module test_numpy

%import "test.i"

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
%}

%include "numpy.i"

%init %{
// Try and run import_array() - at build time we need it to be defined
_import_array();
%}

%apply (int* ARGOUT_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(int* rangevec, int n)}

%inline %{
static void range(int *rangevec, int n)
{
        int i;

        for (i=0; i< n; i++)
                rangevec[i] = i;
}
%}
```

Something like this should work as an alternative to the first two options, but is currently untested.